# How to get Application ID of an App Installed with `gradlew install`?

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-plugin

I am building a plugin for Android Studio.

I would like a function that will

1. Install the current app onto the phone (including building and all the other Gradle tasks)
2. Run the app on the phone straight after installation.

I know that individually, these things can be done from the terminal by calling

1. `gradlew installDebug`
2. `adb shell am start com.example.myapp/.Main`

I am aware the the package `com.example.myapp` is the `applicationId` from the `build.gradle` file. However, it is subject to change, if flavours have a suffix defined, e.g. `com.example.myapp.free.debug`.

My question is, how can I get the application ID of the app that was just installed by `gradlew installDebug` and use it to launch the app on the device?

Answer (score 0):

It is contained in the apk, and can be extracted, for example, like this:

```
aapt dump badging /path/to/the/.apk  | awk '/package/{gsub("name=|'"'"'","");  print $2}'
```